# C# PowerPoint VSTO: Check if Any Slide is in View

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

PowerPoint's interop library exposes `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide` which allows you to test if a slide (any Slide or Master) is currently selected and in the view.

If no slide is currently in the view, then the `View` property is `null`. But here's the twist: you are unable to check `ActiveWindow.View` for null, without raising an exception.

#### My question is this:

How do you check if a slide/master is currently selected without resorting to an ugly try/catch like the following?

```
    internal static bool SlideActive => Slide != null;

    internal static dynamic Slide
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### EDIT:

This is the exception thrown when accessing `Slide` if none is in view:

```
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: View.Slide : Invalid request.  No slide is currently in view.
```

Comment: Check out ActiveWindow.View.ViewType... Seems like the only promising property

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that - but to no avail. But, one month on, I literally just found a solution which I am about to post.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem which involves checking the `ActiveWindow`'s `Pane`'s `Active` property.

A method returning either the active `Slide`/`Master` or `null` could look as follows - no `try`/`catch` required:

```
    internal static dynamic CurrentSlide
    {
        get
        {
            if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Active == MsoTriState.msoTrue &&
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Panes[2].Active == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

First, we need to check if the application is active, followed by checking if the thumbnail pane's corresponding `Pane` is active (to account for the user having de-selected all slides/masters) and, finally, returning our object or null.

Props go out to [this person](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/29a27721-ff31-4e2f-93c8-a17da86fe4b5/vsto-powerpoint-exception-when-trying-to-get-current-slide-index-when-the-selection-is-between?forum=officegeneral/#dda57f92-79db-45dd-a44a-ee9d8ef32d86) having gotten me onto the right track.

Comment: I spoke too early. This won't work if a dialog window steals the focus. So, I'm un-accepting my answer.